# Прокрутка viewpager только в одном направлении (вправо)

Tags: android-viewpager, android

Как возможно ограничить прокрутку viewpager'а только вперёд (вправо)?

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать выкидывать из адаптера просмотренные страницы и обновлять адаптер